# Host wcf service

Tags: wcf, web-services, iis, hosting

I can access my WCF service typing

> http://localhost:1592/TourService.svc/GetPoints

in browser.

However I can't access my service if I put my IP address instead "localhost".

What should I do to make my service hosted on my PC and accessible from other computers?

I created an application in IIS Services and wrote a path to my WCFservice, but it had no effect. It's first time for me when I need to make service "global", so I don't know how to do it

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently hosting under the development web service (Cassini) which doesn't accept off machine connections. You will need to host in IIS by creating an application and pointing it to the physical directory where the .svc file lives

There is a "How To" for IIS hosting [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx)

Comment: It's not clear: I have already a wcf service, I create an application in IIS and point a path to the service. Where I'm wrong?

Comment: What are you seeing if you go to the location `http://localhost/appPath/TourService.svc/GetPoints` where appPath is the application name you created in IIS?

Comment: This error means there is a configuration error in the application. In IIS manager can you look at the handlers for this application and check it has one and only one entry for .svc

Comment: I changed Application pool to the another(with framework 4.0), now I have "HTTP 401.3 - Unauthorized" when try to call web method. )

Comment: make sure that the account has read access to the physical directories

Comment: this [link](http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/HTTP-Error-4013-Unauthorized-Error-While-creating-IIS-70-web-site-on-Windows-Vista.aspx) helped me. Now it's all right!